# I am writing an essay and I need to say, "From here, I would like to talk about my family"

Tags: translation

I'm writing an essay, and to lead into the next paragraph I need to start with, "From here (which is "korekara" I believe) I would like to talk about 2 of my family members, my brother and my mom." I need it in Romaji because I can't read some kanji very well.

Comment: You can try [HiNative!](https://hinative.com/en-US) and you can select question types such as "How do you say this". The response time is usually quite good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Korekara, watakushi (or watashi) wa kazoku ni tsuite ohanashi sasete itadakitai to omoimasu.

--> polite, a little advanced maybe.

(or)

> Korekara, watakushi (or watashi) wa kazoku ni tsuite hanashimasu / hanashitai to omoimasu.

--> simple and polite.

Here, "hanashimasu" is "I will speak" whereas "hanashitai to omoimasu" is "I think I'd like to talk".

Hope this helps! Sorry if its too long.

Answer (score 4):

Since it's an essay, you'd use ここから(は) / kokokara (wa) (from here), rather than これから / korekara (from now), to lead into the next paragraph, like this:

> ここからは、[私]{わたし}の[家族]{かぞく}について｛お[話]{はな}しします。/ お[話]{はな}ししたいと[思]{おも}います。/ [書]{か}きたいと[思]{おも}います。｝
>
> (kokokara wa, watashi no kazoku ni tsuite {o-hanashi shimasu. / o-hanashi shitai to omoimasu. / kakitai to omoimasu.})

Literally: "From here, {I'll talk / I'd like to talk / I'd like to write} about my family."

Alternatively you could start with 「[次]{つぎ}に、・・・」 "tsugi ni," meaning "Next, ..."

To sound more natural you could add 「さて、」 "sate," at the beginning, meaning "Now," or "By the way," as in 「さて、ここからは・・・ 」「さて、次に・・・」.